# Why is my service bus function unable to send an event to the azure durable function which triggered it?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-durable-functions

Working on Azure in .net 6.0 with all up-to-date nugets, we have a durable orchestration, which calls an activity function, which sends a message to a service bus topic, which completes a task, and which then calls RaiseEventAsync on the orchestration to set it running again. We pass the orchestration id in to the service bus function, and it uses that id to raise the return event.

Testing locally, running the functions in Visual Studio, with the Service Bus instance in the cloud, this works well. Running the functions in the cloud, we get an error: `No instance with ID {instanceid} was found`.

We've checked the orchestration id is correct for the durable, and it is: we trace the id when the orchestration is called and then compare that to the error message - it's the same one that's 'not found'.

This seems possibly related to the old race-condition here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/573 - but we understood this was fixed some time ago. We've tried the fix detailed here https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/573#issuecomment-454621618 - but it seems to make no difference.

Here's the orchestration code:

```
InjestionInputModel injestionInput = context.GetInput<InjestionInputModel>();

string mainDocument = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("injestion_getsec_document_raw", injestionInput);

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mainDocument) || injestionInput.ForceRetrival)
{ 

    await context.CallActivityAsync("injestion_document_send_for_sec_extraction", new SendForSecExtractionInput() { Filing = injestionInput.FileInfo, InstanceId = context.InstanceId, IsForced = injestionInput.ForceRetrival });

    _ = await context.WaitForExternalEvent<bool>("WaitForSecDownload");

    mainDocument = await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("injestion_getsec_document_raw", injestionInput);
}
```

Here's the activity function which sends the service bus message:

```
{
    await _injestionService.SendMessageForSecExtraction(sendForSecExtractionInput.Filing, sendForSecExtractionInput.InstanceId, sendForSecExtractionInput.IsForced);
}
```

And here's the code at the end of the Service Bus function which calls back to the orchestration:

```
await client.RaiseEventAsync(message.InstanceId,"WaitForSecDownload", true);
await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(serviceBusReceivedMessage);
```

What are we missing here, and how can we fix this?

Comment: Are you connect to same database locally and in cloud?

Comment: We're not connecting to a database. The service bus function downloads a document for processing from an external location to blob storage. The orchestrator should then continue to call other activities to process the document.

Comment: Whatever you say, it is still a database.  A Rose by any other name still smells as sweet.

Comment: The issue is simple: we're missing the task hub name in the configuration of the service bus function. This isn't brilliantly documented (none of the examples on docs features setting a hub name), so I'll leave this up and answer myself in a couple of days, in case that saves anybody some time in future.